# PowerBI converts the date column to Hijri, how can I make Gregorian the default?

Tags: powerbi

Even though the column is in Gregorian, whenever I make a chart with the date column the charts show the Hijri Calendar.

I've changed the date for my computer to Gregorian but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a suitable culture into Date.ToText().

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/date-totext

[image]

Comment: Do I put this in new measure? and how can I make it for all dates not just 2000?

Comment: You do this in PowerQuery to convert your dates before they get into the model.